# Concurrent blocking queue in C++11

Tags: c++11, concurrency

For message passing in between threads, I'm looking for a concurrent queue with following properties:

- bounded size
- pop method that blocks/waits until an element is available.
- abort method to cancel the wait
- Optional: priority

Multiple producers, one consumer.

The `concurrent_bounded_queue` of TBB would provide that, but I'm looking for alternatives to avoid the additional dependency of TBB.

The application uses C++11 and boost. I couldn't find anything suitable in boost. What are the options?

Comment: Sure, that's an option. However, I think it's always better to use a tested implementation than to reinvent the wheel. Blocking queues are a common thing, so I first would like to check if there is code I can use.

Comment: Why would a new suggested library require less dependancy than TBB, it is an extra library

Comment: Yes, but TBB is problematic in my case (licence, use in in a cross-compile environment)

Comment: To clarify the point of my question: Given this type of queue is standard in other languages (Java,NET), I was surprised I couldn't find something similar in boost. So I wanted check if I overlooked something in boost or if there are articles/blogs/sample code that could help to implement it in C++11.

Comment: @jcm To build a proper concurrent queue is not a trivial task. You need to specify if it is multiple/single-consumer and multiple/single-producer. Have you looked into [Boost.Lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html)?

Comment: @filmor One case is single producer-consumer another case is multiple producers-single consumer

Comment: @filmor Boost.Lockfree gives a concurrent queue, but afaik it does't have the capability to signal the consumer that an element is available (e.g. blocking pop).

Comment: You could easily add this by using a `condition_variable` object.

Comment: Can someone share tested sample of single-producer single-consumer queue with blocking pop. Built on boost + condition_variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Naive implementation using Boost library(circular_buffer) and C++11 standard library.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

struct operation_aborted {};

template <class T, std::size_t N>
class bound_queue {
public:
  typedef T value_type;
  bound_queue() : q_(N), aborted_(false) {}
  void push(value_type data)
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx_);
    cv_pop_.wait(lk, [=]{ return !q_.full() || aborted_; });
    if (aborted_) throw operation_aborted();
    q_.push_back(data);
    cv_push_.notify_one();
  }
  value_type pop()
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx_);
    cv_push_.wait(lk, [=]{ return !q_.empty() || aborted_; });
    if (aborted_) throw operation_aborted();
    value_type result = q_.front();
    q_.pop_front();
    cv_pop_.notify_one();
    return result;
  }
  void abort()
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx_);
    aborted_ = true;
    cv_pop_.notify_all();
    cv_push_.notify_all(); 
  }
private:
  boost::circular_buffer<value_type> q_;
  bool aborted_;
  std::mutex mtx_;
  std::condition_variable cv_push_;
  std::condition_variable cv_pop_;
};
```

Comment: Would a `notify_one` in `push` and `pop` do, too? Oh, and shouldn't it be `|| aborted_` rather than `&& !aborted_`?

Comment: I think you have to unlock the mutex before you notify.

Comment: @filmor well, I agree with you for efficiency. It's a naive sample code ;P and I like this style. (FYI [Why put Signal() inside the critical section?](http://www.chromium.org/developers/lock-and-condition-variable) )

Comment: be carefult because in std::condition_variable::wait can occurs spurious wakeup. so is better have `while ( !q_.full() || aborted_) cv_pop_.wait( lk )` and `while ( !q_.empty() || aborted_ ) cv_push_.wait( lk )`

Comment: @elvis.dukaj [`condition_variable::wait()` with Predicate version](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) has NO spurious wakeup. so I prefer this overload version.

Comment: i don't understand the code but how good is it? clean? tested thoroughly? optimized and fast? can be used in production?

Comment: can it be optimized further for single-producer single-consumer case?

Comment: Thanks @yohjp. Do you think the lambda may be better start with `[&]` instead of `[=]`?